# Mezuza Placement

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, home-house

My main question is how does one determine which side of the doorpost a Mezuza should go on? I believe (though I cannot quote a source) that it is supposed to go on the right side of the door, with the right side being determined by where you enter the room from. However if you have two separate entrances to the home (like a front door and side door) how do you determine where the entry of the room truly is?

Also how high up on the doorpost should the Mezuza be?

Comment: Everyone agrees (I'm sure someone will source) that if there are two doors to a house, that the Mezuzah goes on the right side going into the house on all doors. I believe your question should be asking, what if there are two or three door(way)s into a room, with other rooms sharing the doorway?  For example, many kitchens have entries into the kitchen via the main hallway of a house, and another entry via the dining room.  Does that dining room doorway serve as the entryway to the kitchen, or the entryway to the dining room?  Which room's "right side" gets the Mezuzah?

Comment: Having said that, though, I think the first question is a dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10454/5

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13604/5

Comment: @SethJ I'm not sure that this is quite a duplicate, since it assumes less prior knowledge than the other question does. (In other words, the other question contains some of the answer to this one.) Very close, though.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, If you break down the first question into two sub-questions, 1b is a dupe.

Comment: @SethJ "you believe what my question should be asking". Thats a completely different question and if you want to ask it post in separately. My question is how you determine which "entrance" to use when you have multiple entrances to the house, not what to do about two entrances in one room.

Comment: @Jake, well then the answer is pretty straightforward.  It goes on the right side.  I thought there was some confusion on your part as to which side is "the right side".  But, since all doors on the house go into the house, "the right side" depends on whether you are standing inside or outside (and we always look at it from the outside for placement), and it does not depend on whether you are in front of the house or in back of the house.

Answer (score 4):

> However if you have two separate entrances to the home (like a front door and side door) how do you determine where the entry of the room truly is?

Other doors don't matter; you evaluate mezuzah placement at each door independently.  For each doorway, apply the rules given in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10458/472), which boil down to considerations of traffic flow, which room is more significant, and which way any physical doors involved open.

As noted in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13605/472), there is near-universal agreement that the mezuzah must be placed in the upper third of the doorpost.  If your doorways are very tall, see [this opinion from the Yerushalmi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13058/yerushalmi-versus-bavli-in-halacha/16689#16689) (h/t DoubleAA).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16689/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, thanks!  I've added that to this answer.